# CSS vertial tabs with rotated words

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking to build vertical tabs.

I am running into some issue, because when I rotate it -90 degrees, the END of the div is actually facing up. Hence, if I use absolute positioning, "top" no longer applies because I don't know the width of the div (it varies).

Are there tools/plugins out there which allows me to do this?

Check http://imagebin.ca/view/4ov0ZF.html for more info

Answer (score 1):

hmmm... is it possible to give your tabs fixed dimensions? if so, you can do it without images, which are a nightmare to update, and without javascript (except in IE, which needs js when using the Matrix-filter).

here's an example solution for every browser: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/BjnaS/1/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most robust way to do this would be to use images. That way if Javascript is disabled, it will still continue to work. The implementation should be simple as well (no need to rotate things 90 degrees etc). All the tabs can be in a column of their own and the content can be in a different column.

Answer (score 0):

If you can build all the tabs at once you can simply put them into a table with a single row that can then be rotated.

If you rotate all at once, then there's no problem to keep track of where the previous tab ends.

I suggest using a table as I assume you want to use borders for the tabs and that would be hard to do with inline elements, which would otherwise be required in order to get all tabs to line up horizontally for the single rotation.